# PIC32 only works when shorted to ground

Tags: pic

We're using the PIC32MX795F512L on a number of custom boards. I'm responsible for one design, for which we currently have two prototypes. The first board appears to work perfectly.

On the second, the PIC is mostly unresponsive. Pressing the Reset button doesn't help. Occasionally it will report a Device ID to the PICkit but for the most part it appears dead... until I briefly short the 3.3V supply to ground (don't ask how I discovered this). After that it seems to work just fine - every time, without fail. If I power it down for more than a split second, it begins to fail again.

I think the successful functioning of the first board rules out most design issues, but there's gotta be something wrong somewhere. These were hand-assembled; I've checked all of the connections but I'm wondering if a particular component might be suspect. Any ideas on where to look?

EDIT: thanks for all the replies so far. As requested, a schematic of what's currently connected to the MCLR' line:

[image: schematic]

To clarify, this is our first time designing boards for these chips so there are bound to be some less-than-ideal conditions present (rules we forgot, or thought we were implementing but didn't, etc.); it's clearly serviceable somehow, though, since my first board works.

Comment: How do you reset the PIC32? I.e., at power-up, manually, watchdog, etc.

Comment: Please include a small schematics of what you have connected to the reset pin of your PIC32.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out the problem was our power supply scheme - we had the analog pins on a separate plane, but there's some issue we haven't completely identified with our regulators, wherein some boards don't work this way (it turns out mine wasn't the only one with this problem). Running all Vdd/AVdd pins from the same regulator solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Erik that there could be an issue with the hand assembly of the second board. If the first and second boards are exactly the same design, but one works and the other does not, then it's a component or assembly or freak damage/accident issue.

I have had a recent experience with hand loading 20 small bat tracking boards I designed, which each have small power circuits, memory, gps, and a microcontroller (Atmel ATMEGA328P). of the 20 boards, 16 worked immediately after assembly, but 4 were unresponsive to programming. I could not work out exactly what was wrong, as all solder joints were fine after inspection with microscope, but after SMD re-work replacing the MCU ICs with some spare ones, (TQPF-32 packages, easy stuff) they immediately worked.

I suggest after you try flux + re-heat each solder joint to see if it's a bad join and therefore bad grounding issue, you should attempt to replace the microcontroller IC. Make sure you establish that it is not a solder short circuit or other external fault before doing this! You may just fry/permanently damage another one if you immediately replace before elimination of other options.

Comment: Suggestion: start with the reset pins, then the Vcc pins. Do the same for the decoupling caps. The behavior suggests that something in the startup seems to go wrong, so reset and power are likely culprits.

Comment: For my issues? The replacement ICs fixed it just fine. The ICs could not be successfully flashed with AVR ISCP programming, including having the target powered externally rather than the programmer.

The successful operation after replacement suggests that my reset traces to the ISCP header and the power related traces/capacitors were fine. Also, it was repeatable for each board - I have pretty good/consistent soldering ability. It seems I got a bad batch of MCU chips..

edit:
@hli ah perhaps you meant in addition to my suggestions haha

Comment: flux + reheat won't always do it though, I think because the pins are lifted off, or have a layer of oxidization or hardened flux between.

Comment: I have tried some reflow work - there were some pins lacking solder - which got me from complete non-functionality to the point I'm at now (there was a brief moment post-rework that the board required no encouragement). So my next step will likely be to try some more rework when I get a chance. Thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Since they are hand assembled, look REAL close at the pins, with magnification.  Especially if they are the .4mm/PT package.  You WILL NOT see shorts on these chips until you use something with high enough power.  I personally use a plossl 25m focal length eyepiece.  I have had many funny issues through the years with the 460f512l and 795 that are caused by my own bad hand assembly.

Sometimes I end up flood and sucking all pins to fix something I know is assembly but can't see.  Basically this is running a heavy bead of solder across all the pins, and using solder braid to remove excess solder.

If its not assembly, its likely design, or perhaps the chip was static damaged during assembly.  Did you follow design rule #1 about putting resistors on all pins, or at least those facing anything like the real world?

Comment: I was looking very closely at the pins for quite a while yesterday before getting it to the state it's in now; perhaps fresher eyes tomorrow will reveal something else :) The concept of flooding all the pins makes me nervous but it might be worth a shot.


I'm going to say this about rule #1: I'm not familiar with it, but it's quite likely it wasn't followed, at least not absolutely.


Thanks for the advice.

Comment: Its ok, I just made it up, because its one of the first lessons I learned on one of the first things I built.

Comment: Also, zapped pins can cause strange device behavior.  It could be going into latch up somehow, etc.  Resistors just allow internal pin diodes to handle esd events much better.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is that, for some reason, the power supply voltage is ramping up too slowly for a proper power-on reset to occur. Shorting the supply after it's already up may give the microcontroller a nice fast ramp up on the supply voltage, allowing it to reset properly.

I don't know how this could be related to the problems with the reset button, but it might have to do with what PRG_MCLR is connected to beyond what is shown in the schematic. I would suggest trying a smaller resistance value for the pullup to improve the rising edge transition on this signal.